# A liquid which climbs out of its pot

Tags: physical-chemistry, surface-chemistry, liquids

My Russian born wife recently asked me to buy her a skin remedy widely used in Russia. In English this is the oil of a plant called Sea Buckthorn. It is a thin yellow liquid. My wife put some of this in a small spice bottle which had an open top. I kept finding yellow liquid up the sides of the pot, well above the surface of the liquid and eventually on the surface the pot was standing on.
I very carefully checked this glass pot for any sort of leak in the base but there isn't a leak path. It seems that the oil has climbed out of the pot. After thinking for a long time I seemed to remember that this is a known phenomenon. I can't remember what it is called or what liquids are involved. Please could someone enlighten me ?

Comment: This is known in superfluids, liquid helium at ultra low temperatures. I really doubt that you will observe this "creeping" behavior in ordinary liquids.

Comment: The well-known creeping of KCl out of its solution, even out of its beaker, is documented at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7000175/. Sea Buckthorn (Hippophae) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippophae berry extract is complex: oily and aqueous. It could be that the aqueous material wets the glass, deposits a fat (like KCl comes out) and climbs thru it or over it!